# How to use a same Input action to trigger different events when used on different objects in UNITY?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm facing a small problem with the unity's New Input system.

I'm trying to build a VR game that has floating buttons in the scene. I have used a gaze reticle from Google VR. I'm using a joystick for input in VR mode. Below is the snapshot of my Input actions with bindings with the joystick.
[image]

As you can see I  have an Action called Mouse_Button which is bound to key Y on my joystick (Don't mind about the name "LaserPrinter" unity detects the joystick by this name).

Below is the snapshot of my scene.
[image]
Notice the buttons Input 1 and Input 2. These buttons both get triggered at the same time once I press the button on my joystick as shown[image].

**But I want to trigger a particular button at which the user is looking at in VR mode.**

Below is the c# script I have attached to the buttons .

```
// format for sending button state to blynk



using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class Button_click : MonoBehaviour
{

PlayerControls controls;

public Button myButton;
public Text myText;

private string url_off;
private string url_on;


int cnt=0;

void Awake(){
    
    controls = new PlayerControls();
    
    controls.Gameplay.Mouse_Button.performed += ctx => OnButtonClicked();
    // controls.Gameplay.Move_forward.canceled += ctx => Move;

}


public void OnButtonClicked()
{
    // Debug.Log(cnt);
    if(myButton.name == "Input 1"){
        url_off = //some url;
        url_on = //some url;
    }
    else{
        url_off = //some url;
        url_on = //some url;
    
    }
    
    if(myText.text.Contains("ON")){
        Debug.Log("Button Clicked!");
        myText.text = myButton.name + "\nOFF!";
        StartCoroutine(GetRequest(url_off));
        cnt = 1;
    }
    else{
        Debug.Log("Button Clicked!");
        myText.text = myButton.name + "\nON";
        StartCoroutine(GetRequest(url_on));
        cnt = 0;
    }
    
}

void OnEnable()
{
    controls.Gameplay.Enable();
}

void OnDisable()
{
    controls.Gameplay.Disable();
}

void Start()
{
    // myButton.onClick.AddListener(OnButtonClicked);
    // // // if (BuyText == null)
    // //     BuyText = BuyButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
}

IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
    {
        // Request and wait for the desired page.
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

    }
}
```

}

I have created two empty game objects and attached the script to the objects. For the buttons I have used Event triggers as shown.

[image]

Please help me find a way to trigger only a particular button at which the user is looking at.

I was not able to find any solution online. If the question is repeated, Please let me know.

Comment: Can you not raycast to see what you’re over just like you would with a mouse

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Could you please give more info on raycasting on a gameobject.